# Query taking too long to execute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance

My query takes a lot of time, 22 seconds and above. After 22 seconds, we get more than 900 000 records. We have created indexes on the table which are used in the query:

```
select * from ContactMaster 
where ContactId in (
    select  ContactId 
    from ListContactMaster 
    where ListMasterID in (816,975,945) 
    and ContactId not in (
        select  ContactId 
        from ListContactMaster 
        where ListMasterID in (0)
    ) and (
        isactive='true' 
        or isactive is null
    )
) 
and isactive = 'true' 
and (
    isdeleted='false' 
    or isdeleted is null
) 
and emailaddress not in (
    select emailaddress 
    from supresscontacts
)
and ContactMaster.ContactId not in (
    select DomineSupress.contactid 
    from DomineSupress 
    where DomineSupress.CampaignId=1186 
)
```

Indexes:

- `IX_ListContactMaster_ContactId`,
- `IX_ListContactMaster_IsActive_ContactId`,
- `IX_ListContactMaster_ListMasterID`,
- `IX_ListContactMaster_ListMasterID_ContactId`,
- `IX_ContactMaster_ContactId_IsActive_IsDeleted`

The `ContactMaster` table has more than 50 fields.

Comment: Do you have indexes on DomaineSupress(CampaignId, ContactId) and supresscontacts(EmailAddress)?

Comment: please include EXPLAIN output for your query. Also SHOW CREATE TABLE for your tables would be helpful.

Comment: @redguy - SQL Server doesn't use the `EXPLAIN` keyword to get the execution plan. swaroop you need to look at the execution plan. See [How do I obtain a Query Execution Plan?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7359702/73226) and upload it somewhere if you want help interpreting it.

Comment: Why do you have `IX_ListContactMaster_ListMasterID` and `IX_ListContactMaster_ListMasterID_ContactId`? This seems redundant and wasteful. And if `IsActive` is a bit, the first two indexes might overlap substantially as well.

Comment: You should really include the CREATE TABLE statements for all tables included in your query

Answer (score 1):

You should use joins to reduce lookups between tables and to make better using of indexes during query the data. As expecting your query on relational tables I suggest a pattern as follows.

```
SELECT CM.* from ContactMaster CM 
INNER JOIN ListContactMaster LCM ON CM.ContactId=LCM.ContactId
LEFT JOIN supresscontacts SC ON CM.ContactId=SC.ContactId
LEFT JOIN DomineSupress DS ON CM.ContactId=DS.ContactId
WHERE SC.emailaddress IS NULL AND DS.contactid IS NULL AND DS.CampaignId=1186 AND LCM.ListMasterID IN (816,975,945)
AND LCM.ListMasterID <> 0 AND (LCM.isactive='true' OR LCM.isactive IS NULL)
AND CM.isactive = 'true' AND (CM.isdeleted='false' or CM.isdeleted is null)
```

Hope it will help you to make your query better.